# Papaparse script is not working. It gives a .parse error

Tags: javascript

I have this script inside a MS Sharepoint project. The javascript is using Papaparse to process a uploaded .CSV file. Could really use some help to get this script working. When I execute the code I get error: :TypeError: $(...).parse is not a function.

```
// Parse data from CSV file
function uploadCSV(callBack) {  
    try {
        $('#fileInput').parse({ 
            config: {
                // base config to use for each file
                delimiter: ";",
                header: true,
                //preview: 15,
                async:true,
                dynamicTyping: true,
                skipEmptyLines: true,
                complete: function(results, file) {
                    callBack(results.data);
                }
            },
            before: function() {
                show();
            },
            error: {
                // executed if an error occurs while loading the file
                // or if before callback aborted for some reason
            },
            complete: function(results) {

            }
        });
    }
    catch(err) {
        alert('Error inside function uploadCSV :' + err);
    }
}
```

It looks like the problem has to do with how I load the papaparse library. Here is the source code from the page that loads the library:

```html
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sites/RTZB000/Scripts/JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sites/RTZB000/Scripts/JS/papaparse.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/sites/RTZB000/Scripts/DienstImport/uploadCSV.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <style> 

        ...

    </style>

    <div class="myTable">

        <div class="myTableRow">
            <div class="myTableCell fileUpload">
                <p class="custom-para">Selecteer CSV</p>
                <input type="file" name="csv" id="fileInput" class="upload">
            </div>
            <div class="myTableCell" id="uploadFile">

            </div>
            <div class="myTableCell" id="myUpload">
                <input type="button" class="inputfile-2" onclick="myTrigger()" value="Uploaden" />
            </div>
            <div class="cssload-loader" id="loader">
                <div class="cssload-inner cssload-one"></div>
                <div class="cssload-inner cssload-two"></div>
                <div class="cssload-inner cssload-three"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="myTableCell" id="mySpacer">

            </div>
            <div class="myTableCell" id="link1">
                <a href="/sites/RTZB000/Dienststaten/Historie.aspx">
                    Historie
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="myTableCell" id="link2">
                <a href="/sites/RTZB000/Lists/A_dienststaatTest/AllItems.aspx">
                    Alle items
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="myTableCell" id="link3">
                <a href="/sites/RTZB000/Dienststaten/Vandaag.aspx">
                    Dienststaten
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="myTableCell" id="link4">
                <a href="/sites/RTZB000/Lists/Telefoonlijst_ZHP/AllItems.aspx">
                    Telefoonlijst ZHP
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#uploadFile').hide();
            $('#myUpload').hide();
            $('#loader').hide();

            // Laat de bestandsnaam zien naast de knop
            document.getElementById("fileInput").onchange = function () {
                var myVal = this.value.split(/\\/).slice(-1);
                console.log(myVal);
                document.getElementById("uploadFile").innerHTML = myVal;
                $('#uploadFile').show();
                $('#myUpload').show();
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe good to clarify that this page is part of Microsoft Sharepoint. Above html is embedded inside another html.

Comment: If it isn't defined, then you haven't loaded the library (or if you have, you've loaded it wrong and need to show an [mcve] showing how you load it and jQuery).

Comment: Double check that you have Papaparse included after jQuery

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities here:

- JQuery isn't loading properly. Check your console for errors.
- Something else is overriding your $ variable, probably another version of JQuery. Try to retrieve the original jQuery with $.noConflict().
- The Paraparse library isn't loading as expected. Check your version of Paraparse and look for any errors in your console.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am working on a company pc with no browser console available. Too bad I cannot check for errors.. I have added a script to give alert when jquery is loaded. That works so I can say jquery library is loading properly. Could you explain your second point? How can I use $.noConflict() ?

Comment: @ajdemoed I'm very sorry I missed your comment. If it's not too late, the $.noConflict definition is [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

You can try to load the URL directly to see each library is accessible. You might find that you have the wrong URL due to a typo or something.